# Correct method of retrieving data from another class thats wrapped in using statement

Tags: c#, winforms, using-statement

I'm getting an exception

> Cannot access a disposed object.

I know I'm getting this exception because the object has already been disposed before it had the chance to return the results. What I would like to know is whats the correct way to retrieve the objects. I may have unnecessary steps in my code and may be doing this all wrong?

I have a button click event in my main class. It calls the method shown in the code below. The `GetADComputer` method is located in another class called `ActiveDirectory.cs`. I'm getting my exception when attempting to access the results of the disposed object.

```
public static PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> GetADComputer(string pcName)
{
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        using (ComputerPrincipal computer = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx))
        {
            computer.Name = String.Format("*{0}*", pcName);

            using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
            {
                searcher.QueryFilter = computer;
                return searcher.FindAll();
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: I haven't used `PrincipalSearcher`, but you considered returning a `List<Principal>` by using `return searcher.FindAll().ToList();`? Assuming the `Principal` objects are fully-materialized, that shouldn't need the context any more...

Comment: @JonSkeet the Principal objects are not fully materialized, DirectoryServices lazy loads properties. (you might be able to change that, but I don't know how)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Boo hiss :(

Comment: It's @JonSkeet! haha. Thanks for the reply. Using the list approach works but I'm looking into what @ScottC said about the Object Materialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is DirectoryServices uses Lazy Loading for it's information, so because you closed the context you can't retrieve the information from the `Principal` anymore.

You have two options, either pass the `PrincipalContext` in to the query so it does not go out of scope when you return:

```
public static DoSomthing()
{
    using(var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    using(PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = GetADComputer("some Name", ctx))
    {
        //do something with the result here.
    }
}

public static PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> GetADComputer(string pcName, PrincipalContext ctx)
{
    using (var computer = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx))
    {
        computer.Name = String.Format("*{0}*", pcName);

        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
        {
            searcher.QueryFilter = computer;
            return searcher.FindAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Or you will need to convert the results in to something that does not rely on lazy loading so you can close the connection to the directory server.

```
public static List<ComputerInfo> GetADComputer(string pcName, PrincipalContext ctx)
{
    using (var computer = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx))
    {
        computer.Name = String.Format("*{0}*", pcName);

        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
        {
            searcher.QueryFilter = computer;
            using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                return result.Select(p=> new ComputerInfo(p.Name, p.SID)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
} 

public class ComputerInfo
{
    public ComputerInfo(string name, SecurityIdentifier sid)
    {
        Name = name;
        SID = sid;
    }

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public SecurityIdentifier SID {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This works great! I tried this approach for another AD query method i have. The other method uses the System.DirectoryServices class and it throws the "Cannot access a disposed object." exception. Does your reply only apply to my example code that used the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement class?

Comment: @HiTech It is the same underlying issue, either keep the context open by passing it in as a parameter or convert the return object to something that has no dependencies on the context.